# Google Maps API v3 - infoWindows all have same content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've been having problems with the infoWindows and Google Maps API v3.
Initially, I've ran into the problem that everyone else has of closing infoWindows when opening a new one.
I thought to have solved the problem by defining "infowindow" beforehand. Now they close when I click on a new marker, but the content is the same. 
How should I re-structure my code to make sure the content is the right one each time - and only one infoWindow is open at a given time?

Thank you!

Paul

```
var allLatLngs = new Array();
var last = 0;
var infowindow;

function displayResults(start, count){
    if(start === undefined){
        start = last;
    }
    if(count === undefined){
        count = 20;
    }
    jQuery.each(jsresults, function(index, value) {
        if(index >= start && index < start+count){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(value);
        $("#textresults").append(index + ": <strong>" + obj.name + "</strong> " + Math.round(obj.distanz*100)/100 + " km entfernt" + "<br/>");

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.geo_lat, obj.geo_lon);
            allLatLngs.push(myLatlng);

        var contentString = '<strong>'+obj.name+'</strong>';

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  //title:"Hello World!"
              });
            marker.setMap(map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            if (infowindow) { infowindow.close(map,marker); }
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }
    });

    last = start+count;
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

You are calling

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

inside an jQuery.each iteration, thus, i think it will be calling the last item in the iteration. 
Modify your code so you get this inside the jQuery.each iteration.

```
var curItem = 1;   
google.maps.event.addListener(aMarker, "click", function(idx, theContent) {
   return function() {
       alert(idx);  //Should print 1 marker1, 2 for marker 2, to show it's ok.

       //Your stuff...
       if (infowindow) { 
          infowindow.close(map,marker); 
       }       
       infowindow.setContent(theContent);  
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
   }
} (curItem++, contentString)
);
```

When you see "return function()" I'm using a [javascript closure](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html). I've just used this closure for other stuff. I've got rid of other previous variations in my previous answer.

Comment: Hi johncatfish,

thank you for your answer. However, I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to use it. I've replaced the infowindow.open(map,marker) with your code but it only throws errors.
Could you please explain a bit more?

Thank you,
Paul