# Google Maps API infowindows all have the same content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the old infowindows in a loop problem where the content for the last loop is showing in all infowindows. Yes I know there are several questions about this already on Stack Overflow but none of them seem to work for me.

This is my JavaScript:

```
var map;
var geocoder;

$(function () {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: startZoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng)
    }
    var marker, i;

    $('#map-canvas').height($('#map-canvas').width() / 2);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: startZoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLng)
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    if ( ! isAddress && $('#country').val() > 0) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': $('#country').find('option:selected').text()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
            }
        });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < distributors.length; i++) {
        var $distributor = distributors[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng($distributor.latitude, $distributor.longitude),
            map: map
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var html = '<div class="container-fluid" style="width: 300px">\
            <h1 class="row-fluid">\
                '+($distributor.logo ? '<div class="span3"><img src="'+$distributor.logo+'" style="width: 100%"></div>' : '')+'\
                <span class="span9">'+$distributor.name+'</span>\
            </h1>\
            <div class="row-fluid">\
                <div class="span6">'+$distributor.address+'<br>'+$distributor.postcode+'</div>\
                <div class="span6">'+($distributor.url ? '<a href="'+$distributor.url+'">'+$distributor.url+'</a>' : '')+'<br>'+$distributor.contactNumber+'</div>\
            </div>\
        </div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(html);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

})
```

So far I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889416/google-maps-api-v3-infowindows-all-have-same-content), but the variables mentioned don't match what I have and I couldn't make them match up, it just didn't work.

I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475830/google-maps-api-v3-markers-all-share-the-same-infowindow), but instead of getting different content it removed all but one of my markers.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me sort this out?

Comment: This is a closure scope issue. see a similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158598/google-maps-api-v3-adding-an-infowindow-to-each-marker

Comment: If it really is a different issue, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  What does your HTML/CSS look like?  Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @geocodezip I've not said it's a different issue, I said the methods provided in the other answer either aren't working for me or I can't figure out how to implement them given how my code currently is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this after creating infoWindow and html objects:

```
marker.html = html;
```

Then build your event listener like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infoWindow.open(map, this);
                });
```